# Why do I get the "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" eror? What did I not / incorrectly install?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I started programming a Discord bot with javascript, but ran into an error that I don't know how to fix.
Please help me =)

````
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
} ```
````

Comment: That usually means it’s not finding a file found by `require()`.  Either way, how do you expect us to help when you didn’t show any actual code?

Comment: This error can be due to several reasons: Incorrectly specified path, incorrectly specified file type, or this file does not exist, if this is a module, then it must be installed by `npm i module_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a file which dosent exist. Even i had this error and in my case i was trying to run

```
node app.js
```

but I had named my file as index.js, so I had to run.

```
node index.js
```

I had a big facepalm after that :P